# using a for-loop in a table in python

Tags: python, html, for-loop

I am trying to  make a table that sorts out high-grossing films and the most similar films to them.  All of the code is completed but I'm having trouble finishing the table.

my code:

```
#import the data from the csv file and use DictRead to interpret the information.

import csv

csv_file = open("moviestats_med.csv")
csv_data = csv.DictReader(csv_file)


#create dictionary of films and their directors.
direct = {}
#create dictionary of films and their genres.
genre = {}
#create dictionary of films and each main actor.
actor1 = {}
actor2 = {}
actor3 = {}
#create dictionary of films and their worldwide gross.
gross = {}
#create dictionary of films and the year they came out.
year = {}

name = {}
#iterate over the csv file to fill the dictionaries.
for c in csv_data:
    direct[c['name']] = c['director']
    genre[c['name']] = c['genre']
    actor1[c['name']] = c['actor1']
    actor2[c['name']] = c['actor2']
    actor3[c['name']] = c['actor3']
    gross[c['name']] = c['Worldwide Gross']
    year[c['name']] = c['date']
    name[c['name']] = c['name']    

#create a two-variable function to deterime the FavActor Similarity score:
def FavActorFunction(film1,film2):
    #set the result of the FavActor formula between two films to a default of 0.
    FavActorScore = 0
    #add 3 to the similarity score if the films have the same director.
    if direct[film1] == direct[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 3
    #add 2 to the similarity score if the films are in the same genre.
    if genre[film1] == genre[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 2
    #add 5 to the similarity score for each actor they have in common.                    
    if actor1[film1] in (actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
        FavActorScore += 5
    if actor2[film1] in (actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
        FavActorScore += 5
    if actor3[film1] in (actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
        FavActorScore += 5    
    #print the resulting score.                    
    return FavActorScore

#create a function to find the film with the greatest Worldwide Gross per year.   
def MaxGrossFinder(c):
    #set the intial maximum gross to zero.
    MaxGross = 0  
    #replace the MaxGross with any film in that year that has a greater gross.
    for film in year:                      
        f = int(gross[film])                        
        if year[film] == c:
            if f > MaxGross:
                MaxGross = f
                max = film
    #print the year and the max value for that year.                   
    return max

#create a dictionary for the max grossing films of each year from 2000-2007.
max_films = {}                       
#create a list of years from 2000-2007.                       
for c in ['2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007']:
    max_films[c] = MaxGrossFinder(c)



if 'a' == 'a':
    max_list = []
    MaxSimilarity = 0
    for d in year:
        f = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
        if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
            if year[d] == c:
                if f > MaxSimilarity:
                    MaxSimilarity = f
                    max = d
    max_list.append(max)

    MaxSimilarity2 = 0            
    for d in year:
        g = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
        if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
            if d != max:
                if year[d] == c:
                    if g > MaxSimilarity2:
                        MaxSimilarity2 = g
                        max2 = d
    max_list.append(max2)

    MaxSimilarity3 = 0            
    for d in year:
        h = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
        if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
            if d != max and d != max2:
                if year[d] == c:
                    if h > MaxSimilarity3:
                        MaxSimilarity3 = h
                        max3 = d

    max_list.append(max3)



    MaxSimilarity4 = 0            
    for d in year:
        i = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
        if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
            if d != max and d != max2 and d != max3:
                if year[d] == c:
                    if i > MaxSimilarity4:
                        MaxSimilarity4 = i
                        max4 = d
    max_list.append(max4)




print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
print "<table border=1>"

print "<tr>"
print "<th><font color=green>Year</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=blue>Highest Grossing Film</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>2nd Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>3rd Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>4th Most Similar</font></th>"
print "</tr>"


for c in sorted(max_films):
    print "<tr><th>"
    print c
    print "<td>"
    print max_films[c]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[0]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[1]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[2]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[3]
    print "</td></tr></th>"
```

the table I come up with is mostly correct but the "Most Similar" films in every row all correspond to the first year [2000].  How can I alter my code so that the "Most Similar" films will correspond to the right data?

Answer (score 3):

Some advices:

- Why do you use "actor1 actor2 actor3" rather than `main_actors = []`? You can store dictionnaries inside!
- You can also use `seq` in place of `for c in [2000, …. ]`
- Finally, you could use printf like formatting with your strings (at the end) and have:

`print "<tr><th>%s<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td></td></tr></th>" % (c, max_films[c], max_list[0], max_list[1], max_list[2], max_list[3])`

But I think the actual problem is html in your case: you must not use th in eatch row. The syntax is the following:

```
<table>
   <tr><th>Colname1</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname3</th></tr>
   <tr><td>value 11</td><td>value 12</td><td>value 13</td></tr>
   <tr><td>value 21</td><td>value 22</td><td>value 23</td></tr>
   <tr><td>value 31</td><td>value 32</td><td>value 33</td></tr>
</table>
```

But I may have missed something on you script.

Answer (score 1):

```
for c in sorted(max_films):
    print "<tr><th>"
    print c
    print "<td>"
    print max_films[c]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[0]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[1]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[2]
    print "</td><td>"
    print max_list[3]
    print "</td></tr></th>"
```

You print the same variables max_list[0:4] every time you go through the loop. Since you don't change those variables of course you get the same output each time.

You need to either move your logic to decide which is most similiar into the loop or create a new loop which stores the most similar in a list which can fetch inside your loop.